# Read contact email of logged in user [Chrome Extension]

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I want to build a Chrome extension which will read all the contact email addresses and read all the emails form the 'Primary' tab, now it will remove the mails that are not from the ones in the contact email.

My question is how can I read the all email addresses from the contact list?

Comment: There are many ways. Question too broad. Show what you tried and what issues it has. Look at using the api directly with oauth (chrome identity) or scrapping the page html.

Comment: 1) I don't want to use Contacts API or https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity
2) So, I guess the only way I can do it, is scrapping the page?

Comment: Scraping may not work because the page may not load all contacts or details. The api is trivial to use.

Comment: I didn't want users to interact with permissions, that is why I thought of using scraping. 
From what I understand to accept permission for using the API, I will also need to interact with a web server, which I don't want. I guess I'll need to figure something else out. Thanks